# Distribution plot for time series

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, data-visualization

I have a case I would like to study with Python: each time someone is coming close to a sensor placed at the entrance of a shop, the date/hour is saved and a device_id is emitted (always=1).
Here is the dataset:
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajTnL.png)

I would like to plot a distribution plot over the days/hours to see the evolution of the number of visitors along the day.

```
data = pd.read_csv('analysis.csv', index_col='device_local_date', , parse_dates=True)
```

I tried to plot the curve with distplot or factorplot but I didn't manage to get a proper one.
What do you think is the best way of representing it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you make the data accessible?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, I can just show the extract on the picture, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[boucho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13995635/boucho)

I think what you are looking for can be solved by following these steps:

```
data = pd.read_csv('analysis.csv', index_col='device_local_date', , parse_dates=True)
data['hour'] = [x.hour for x in data['device_local_date']]
data['day']  = [x.day for x in data['device_local_date']]

sns.distplot(data['hour'])
```

This is what you will get

[image_link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEqvI.png)

On the other hand, if want you want to see is the number of customers per hour each day, then the code looks like this:

```
hours = data['hour'].unique()
hours.sort()

days = data['day'].unique()
days.sort()

for day in days:
    day_df = data[data['day'] == day]
    plt.plot(hours, [day_df[day_df['hour'] == hour].shape[0] for hour in hours], label = str(day))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is the result:

[Number of customers per hour each day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgJzd.png)

Hope this is useful!